# POST method not working on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, apache, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yesterday I set up Amazon EC2 and RDS in a VPC, installed PHP and Apache on EC2. What I can do is to connect to EC2, connect to DB (mySQL) from EC2 by running a PHP script, connect do DB from local machine using MySQL workbench with SSH tunneling. The thing is I **cannot** use POST method in my PHP script, the script runs but it doesn't obtain any values. Here is my easiest script for testing purposes (I use Postman for tests):

```
    <?php

    $response = array();

    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['login'] != '' && $_POST['password'] != '' ){
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $md_password = md5($_POST['password']);

        require_once 'config.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, db_name) or die("Connection error");

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "insert into users(login, md_password) values ('$login', '$md_password')");


        if($result) {

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Registration successful.";

            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {

            $user_exist_check = mysqli_query($con, "select * from users where login = '$login'");

            if ($user_exist_check) {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "User already exists.";

                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {        

            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Error. Try again.";

            echo json_encode($response);
            }   
        }
    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Fill all the fields.";

        echo json_encode($response);

    }

    ?>
```

If I run the script from Apache on my localhost it works fine:

[image]

But then, when I try to execute the same script from EC2 i get either 500-internal server error or 200 OK but without a good response:

[image]

Do I have to setup something else to get it to work? Script with only inserting to DB (without any POST method) works okay.

If it is important - my plan is to build an Android application that is connected to mySQL DB via EC2 (passing JSONS), with additional storage for photos on S3. In addition I would like to later build a webapp, that could also use the same S3 storage and DB. I think that it should work and now only those POST method are not working...

Comment: is there is any error message which you are getting on server side in your application logs or apache access and error logs ?

Comment: Sample access log line:
` xx.xx.xxx.xx - - [22/Mar/2017:23:48:55 +0000] "POST /register_user_new.php HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" `

Comment: Any error on server side ? access log looks fine...

Comment: @AmitK Hey. Strange thing, because after some time it just started to work, and works fine until now...

Comment: Ha ha, you must have missed something :)